VSCode Jest extension fails to rerun tests on save with typescript
I want to use the Jest VSCode extension, because it offers in-editor code coverage. I have set the default runMode as follows:
"jest.runMode": {
        "type": "on-save",
        "coverage": true
    }

When I run the following tests I get the expected results, which is for all test to pass (there are more test, but I'm inserting only this test because I'm going to change it to highlight the problem):

And we get all green:

Now, if I inverse the expected test result (by adding ".not") I expect the following behavior on save:

Save the test file
tsc -w transpiles the test to a .test.js file
VSCode Jest extensions reruns the *test.js files
Jest extension throws an Error because we purposfly made the test fail

What happens in actuallity is:

Save the test file
tsc -w transpiles the test to a .test.js file
VSCode Jest extensions reruns the *test.js files
Jest extension does not throw an error, and all tests are green???

Inversing the test:

Still all green??? :

